# Bootstrap4 navbar collapse button not responding

Tags: html, css

I can see the navbar however when I click it to have dropdown it is not responding.

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <!-- Logo -->
        My name
    </a>

        <!-- collapse when screen get small -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive"> 
    <!-- ml-auto: Setting navbar to right -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <!-- active class makes current location brighter -->
            <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- #home goes to <div id="home">  -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about_me">About Me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#References">References</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am using bootstrap4 and all the classes are from bootstrap. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML/CSS looks good.  Make sure you're including jQuery, poppper.js and `bootstrap.js` in that order or else any functionality that depends on it will not work.

Pasted it into [this codepen](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/ardgGN) and it works fine.

Comment: I've appended bootstrap on top of my page, do the same for others?

Comment: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/popper.min.js"</script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: You 're still missing ```bootstrap.js```